# PDF.js not rendering document in Windows 7 and IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, pdf.js

We have embed using an iframe PDF.js using the latest version downloaded from their site.
The problem we are having is that for some users the document is not being rendered on windows 7 with IE 11. Instead of the content of the document they get a blank page.
We narrow it to that configuration, but what is more confusing to us is that if we log with another user to the same machine (using remote desktop), the other user can see the document without any troubles.

I can post the pdf document since it contains sensitive data from our customers/clients. How ever the pdf contains some text and images.

We check the settings and found nothing different, except the fact of an intel graphics driver that may be old.

Do someone know if there is an specific setting on IE or something related to PDF.js that needs like webgl or similar to work?

sorry for being vague but i have no clue and i'm a little bit lost trying to figure out this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to a problem with Windows 7 32bit and a setting in the browser to control the Hardware acceleration feature (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2528233) if we disable it the document renders just fine. Could it be related to graphics card drivers?

Comment: Is your graphics card drivers out-of-date?

Comment: yes it was, and that fixed the problem, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of the PDF Js library and updating the drivers for the intel 4000 graphic card solved the problem. It was only happening in machines with that configuration.